# Access UserControl property on MasterPage from derived page? This used to work!

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, master-pages

This is driving me crazy. In the past I have been able to have a master page, put a user control on that page, and create a read-only property referencing that usercontrol, and access the usercontrol and all its properties from the derived page. Now I am getting this error:
The type ‘XXXX’ is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'App_Web_2zw4yn55, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
I looked at older projects and see that I was able to do this. I am using .Net 4.0 now, but not sure that is an issue.

My page declarations look like this...

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Main.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPages_Main" %>
<%@ Register src="../UserControls/WebUserControl.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind for Master Page:

```
public UserControls_WebUserControl TheWebControl { get { return this.WebUserControl1; } }
```

Derived Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Main.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/Main.master" %>
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/Main.master" %>
```

Code Behind for Derived Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.TheWebControl.Pagetitle = "Hey";
    }
```

If I put a reference, in the page declarations of the derived page, for the usercontrol it works, but I shouldn’t have to do that. I am not sure what is going on. I have never had to do this before. The only thing I can think of is that my web.config was setup differently, but even in my old pages I am not seeing any direct references to the usercontrol.

UPDATE:
I may have been mistaken. Looking back at the older code again, I did, indeed, add a reference in the page directives to the usercontrol on the derived page.

Perhpas there is anohter way of doing this without having to add the directive?

Comment: May not help but worth a shot... Usually when I've seen those types of errors it's not because a specific problem actually exists, it's just the aspnet compiler getting some compiled files mixed up. Have you tried touching the web.config or recycling the app pool on that web to make sure everything gets recompiled? Also try clearing everything out of the temporary ASP.NET files. It may be that you're actually having a real error, but it's worth a shot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken. Looking back at the older code again, I did, indeed, add a reference in the page directives to the usercontrol on the derived page.